# New to eOS, couple cutomization questions

Tags: wingpanel

I really like the OS, but there are a couple things I am missing from other distros.

1. How can I get icons in the top tray? I like having my VPN and Syncthing visible and accessible at a glance at the top right.
2. How can I enable window preview for apps in the bottom launcher? Especially when I have multiple windows open in Firefox, it is annoying to have to cycle through them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that in order for them to appear on the top panel, the application must be made especially for eOS. Dev want everyone to program apps exclusively for eOS...

Well...

The solution to this is install a third party application.

You'll need the following dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libgranite-dev libindicator3-dev
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install libwingpanel-dev indicator-application
```

now install this:
https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana/blob/master/com.github.lafydev.wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.7_odin.deb

then:

Edit the file

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop
```

Search the parameter:

> OnlyShowIn= and add "Pantheon" at the end of the line :
> OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;

Save your changes with Ctrl+O then Ctrl+x to exit

After do all this, just reboot and enjoy eOS

Source: https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

If this solves your question don't forget to mark as solved